# How do I implement multi-texturing using OpenGL ES 1.1 to combine separate RGB and alpha PKMs?

Tags: android, opengl-es, multitexturing

I have been trying to reduce the memory footprint of my textures in a Android game that I wrote without too much success. Based on research that I have done it seems that a good approach is to compress my textures using ETC1 since that is the mostly wided supported format for Android devices.

I am able to create the necessary PKMs from my PNGs using Mali ARM - no problems there. I can also render these PKMs just fine using ETC1Utils - again no problems so far.

The problem comes in with trying to handle alphas. I used Mali to create a separate alpha file for my PNGs, i.e. "xxx.png" is compressed into "xxx.pkm" and "xxx_alpha.pkm". The one approach suggested to me in a different question that I asked was to use multi-texturing to combine these two textures since I can't use fragment shaders in OpenGL ES 1.1.

And this is where I am stuck. I am not too familiar with this stuff and I am not making much head way. Basically, as soon as I try to combine with my alpha texture, everything is just rendered white.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class Texture {

    GLGraphics glGraphics;
    FileIO fileIO;
    String fileName;
    int textureId;
    int minFilter;
    int magFilter;

    public int width;
    public int height;

    private boolean loaded = false;

    public Texture(GLGame glGame, String fileName) {
        this.glGraphics = glGame.getGLGraphics();
        this.fileIO = glGame.getFileIO();
        this.fileName = fileName;
        load();
    }

    public void load() {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        int[] textureIds = new int[2];
        gl.glGenTextures(2, textureIds, 0);
        textureId = textureIds[0];

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = fileIO.readAsset(fileName + ".pkm");

            int rgbTexture = textureId;

            gl.glActiveTexture(GLES10.GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, rgbTexture);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GLES11.GL_MODULATE);

            ETC1Texture etcTexture = ETC1Util.createTexture(inputStream);
            ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, GLES11.GL_RGB, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, etcTexture);

            int alphaTexture = textureId[1];

            gl.glActiveTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE1);
            gl.glBindTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, alphaTexture);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GLES11.GL_COMBINE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_COMBINE_RGB, GLES11.GL_REPLACE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC0_RGB, GLES11.GL_PREVIOUS);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GLES11.GL_SRC_COLOR);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_MODULATE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC0_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC1_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_PREVIOUS);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND1_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_SRC_ALPHA);

            InputStream inputStreamAlpha = fileIO.readAsset(fileName + "_alpha.pkm");
            ETC1Texture etcAlphaTexture = ETC1Util.createTexture(inputStreamAlpha);
            ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, GLES11.GL_RGB, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, etcAlphaTexture);

            setFilters(GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

            width = etcTexture.getWidth();
            height = etcTexture.getHeight();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load texture '" + fileName + "'", e);
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }

        loaded = true;
    }

    public void reload() {
        load();
        bind();
        setFilters(minFilter, magFilter);
        glGraphics.getGL().glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public void setFilters(int minFilter, int magFilter) {
        this.minFilter = minFilter;
        this.magFilter = magFilter;

        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
    }

    public void bind() {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        loaded = false;

        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        int[] textureIds = { textureId };
        gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() {
        return loaded;
    }

    public void setLoaded(boolean loaded) {
        this.loaded = loaded;
    }
}
```

My main concern is the load() method. This code was put together through snippets that I have found on the web and coupled with my lack of understanding of multi-texturing in general, I have clearly gone wrong somewhere. Also note that when I render my textures I call:

```
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);        

camera.setViewportAndMatrices();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// call some objects that do my rendering stuff here

gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

When I render a texture I call the bind() method on my Texture class. As you can see, this binds to my global textureId variable which was used as the RGB PKMs ID when loading. I am not even sure if this is correct. Should I be binding to the RGB's ID or the alpha's ID? Or is that not even close to being on the right track? My problem may also relate to how I am loading the alphas using ETC1Utils - I have no idea if this approach is correct or not.

I am really quite stuck so any help pointing out where I have gone wrong and some sort of explanation about how multi-texturing is supposed to be implement to combine ETC1 alphas and RGBs would really be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I was performing multi-texturing incorrectly. The answer for this question helped me correct my approach: [Which texture do I bind to when implementing multi-texturing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75456/which-texture-do-i-bind-to-when-implementing-multi-texturing)

After sorting that out I eventually realised through my own experimentation and through some other questions that I asked that this is not really possible using OpenGL ES 1.1. The reason is that the alpha PKM stores its alpha values in the RGB channels and there is no decent way to combine these RGB values into a single alpha using multi-texturing.

So you need to upgrade to OpenGL ES 2.0 to be able to handle alphas with ETC1. Some more detail is given in the answer to this question: [Is there a way to use the RGB channels of a texture as the alpha channel when applying multitexturing using OpenGL ES 1.1?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-rgb-channels-of-a-texture-as-the-alpha-channel-when-ap)